# how to convert rows into factors in R?

Tags: r, matrix, r-factor

For example, I have a matrix:

```
> a = cbind(sample(c(0,1),6,replace=T), sample(c(0,1),6,replace=T))
> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    1
[4,]    1    0
[5,]    1    0
[6,]    1    1
```

I want to make a object `b` out of `a` so that `b` is a factor, with each level represent a different row in `a`. In this case, `b` would be:

```
> b
[1] 1 1 2 3 3 4
Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

I can do it in a dirty way, but I am wondering if there is an elegant solution?

Comment: How big is dataset? will `a` always have 2 columns? will `a` always contain only `integer`, only `numeric` or only `characters`?

Comment: What is the "dirty" way that you currently use? How do we ensure that our way isn't also dirty?

Comment: the dirty way what I thought is to use the `paste` to concatenate each row. But I forgot I also could use `apply` function to vectorize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution :

```
 b <- apply(a, 1, paste, collapse="_")
 b <- factor(b, levels=unique(b), labels=1:length(unique(b)))
```

Comment: This was my original idea, and I think `paste` would be faster than `interaction`, but not sure what the OP has already tried.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I would say that as always it depends of the volume of data. When this one grows then paste is faster than interaction.

Comment: it's not just the volume of data. As the number of interactions increase, since paste is vectorized, it will definitely be faster. Adding `drop = FALSE` speeds up `interaction` a bit, but I'm not sure by how much.

Answer (score 5):

Not knowing what your current "dirty" way is, here is a possible solution:

```
> aFac <- interaction(data.frame(a), lex.order=TRUE)
> factor(aFac, levels = levels(aFac), labels = seq_along(levels(aFac)))
[1] 1 1 2 3 3 4
Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

Where:

```
a <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
               .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
```

The only reason I've used `lex.order = TRUE` is to match your specific output.

---

Another possibility is:

```
> aFac <- interaction(data.frame(a), lex.order=TRUE, drop = TRUE)
> factor(as.numeric(aFac))
[1] 1 1 2 3 3 4
Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

The `drop = TRUE` is to drop any unused levels from `interaction`, as we would get with the example in the comments below.

To demonstrate the influence of `drop = TRUE`, consider the following, paying attention to the resulting factor levels:

```
> b <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(6L,2L))
> bFac1 <- interaction(data.frame(b), lex.order=TRUE)
> bFac2 <- interaction(data.frame(b), lex.order=TRUE, drop=TRUE)
> factor(as.numeric(bFac1))
[1] 3 4 3 2 2 4
Levels: 2 3 4
> factor(as.numeric(bFac2))
[1] 2 3 2 1 1 3
Levels: 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on simplicity of data, following can be one way to do it..

```
a
##      V1 V2
## [1,]  0  0
## [2,]  0  0
## [3,]  0  1
## [4,]  1  0
## [5,]  1  0
## [6,]  1  1

hash <- apply(a, 1, paste, collapse = "/")
b <- factor(hash, labels = 1:length(unique(hash)))
b
## [1] 1 1 2 3 3 4
## Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: since your answer came later than droopy's, I accepted droopy's answer. but thanks! +1